# Android AppBar SearchView takes all the space with no back arrow

Tags: java, android, xml, searchview

I want to view the back arrow behind the SearchView.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4iBxb.png
XML:

```
<item android:id="@+id/search"
      android:title="@string/search_btn_hint"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
      android:titleCondensed="@string/search_btn_hint"
      app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
      app:showAsAction="always" />
```

I tried to use "collapseActionView|ifRoom" but it didn't give the focus to the SearchView. My java code to give the focus:

```
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search, menu);
final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false); // Do not iconify the widget; expand it by default
searchView.setQueryHint("Search...");
searchView.setFocusable(true);
searchView.setIconified(false);
searchView.requestFocusFromTouch();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a toolbar to your .xml layout file (it's a Relative Layout in my case, but that's not a demand. Could be a Linear Layout or whatever, just what you're used to use inside your activities layout):

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/Background"
tools:context=".YourActivity">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/YOUR_TOOLBAR_ID_HERE"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/Header"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            android:textSize="20sp">
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Instantiate your activity's layout inside OnCreate():

```
setContentView(R.layout.your_activity_layout);
```

And do something like this, right after instantiating the layout:

```
mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.YOUR_TOOLBAR_ID_HERE);
setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setTitle(null);
getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

add this to your searchview inside your java class

```
searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
```

and finally, the xml searchable menu item:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_searchable_activity"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_white_24dp"
    android:title="@string/title_activity_searchable"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"/>
```

It works for me. Hope it helps.

Comment: where should i add the toolbar menu or activity ?